# Query on Expectation value of Spin-X operator being Invariant with transformation of BASIS

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, quantum-spin, matrix-elements

Please correct my calculations below. Where did I go wrong? What did I assume wrong?

[image]

Thanks & Regards,
Sarath Chandra.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.